# RxSwift in Framework crash

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, rx-swift

I build framework, first new project when I test my application - all be ok.
Next step i try build in SDK (framework) package and add this to my project and...
There is a problem... set scheme on build - OK, when I try set scheme on release my SDK crash on: 
`onDisposed: {}).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

I don't know why my project test its ok, but when i try add it to SDK in release is CRASH ;/

Maybe someone had a similar problem.
RxSwift 3.6.1 - on SDK, project test and application when i add package SDK.

Thanks for help! :)

Edit: 
When setting up a SDK project configuration on debug - it only works on debug configuration (when release is crash related to RxSwift) when the project is setup as release and throws into the package it works only at release configuration (on debug is crash associated with RxSwift).
I want to build one package which will support release and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because this method is deprecated for a long while. Try using *.disposed(by: disposeBag)* instead.